# Graphql with mutation spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

My schema file is

```
type Mutation {
createCustomer(name: String!, email: String!, product: [Product]): Customer
}

input Product {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    price: Int
}

interface Person {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
}

type Customer implements Person {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    product: [Product] 
}
```

I want to insert customer detail here which has product list as input. My query is

```
mutation {
  createCustomer(
    name: "kitte", 
    email: "kitte@gmail.com",
    product: [
      {
         name: "soap", 
             price: 435,
      }
    ]
  ) 
  {
    id
    name
    email
    product{name}

  }
}
```

But I am getting exception

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "validationErrorType": "WrongType",
      "message": "Validation error of type WrongType: argument value ArrayValue{values=[ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='name', value=StringValue{value='dars76788hi'}}, ObjectField{name='price', value=IntValue{value=123}}]}, ObjectValue{objectFields=[ObjectField{name='name', value=StringValue{value='darr'}}, ObjectField{name='price', value=IntValue{value=145}}]}]} has wrong type",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "errorType": "ValidationError"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't understand what is the error. And how to pass list to mutation. I have referred some examples but not able to insert product as list.

Comment: Have you tried to get some product fields in your mutation, like `mutation { createCustomer(...) { id, name, email, product {name} } }`?

Comment: It solved this error. But getting new error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are passing the right type of objects to your mutation. GraphQL needs separate types for input fields. In your schema, Product types should be something like this and you should change the mutation accordingly.

```
type Product {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    price: Int
}

input ProductInput {
    name: String!
    price: Int
}

input CustomerInput {
    ...
    products: [ProductInput]
}
```

There are couple of very useful examples in the docs, see [Mutations and Input Types](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/)

Comment: It is storing customer to db. but not able to return product by products {

      name
    }

Comment: mutation Customer  {
  createCustomer(name: "trrth", email: "night", product: [{id:"1", name: "thrh", price: 123}]) {
    id
    name
    email
    products {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

Comment: It should be `product {id, name}` based on your schema. Watch for single product vs products and add a coma between id and name.

Comment: Never mind the comas :) I see that you were just writing quickly. You are getting Wrong type error so try to add `type Product {...}` in addition to your input type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have resolved this by taking input type for mutation and returning type instread of input type. So i am not getting type cast error now.